# JavaFX css vs Preferences

Tags: css, javafx, preferences

I am wondering what is the right way to make a css-styled application user-configurale by Preferences/ Settings?

I would like to give the user a choice to define some colors via the application's preferences menu which are right now defined via css.

For example, I have a 'warning' color defined: (`root.css`:)

```
.warning {
    -fx-background-color: coral;
}
```

Now I would like to add a [color picker](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/ui_controls/color-picker.htm) to let the user override this setting.

Comment: You could generated a "user-customizable css file", which gets overwritten/configured via its own preferences/settings-dialogue. This way you can give the user full access, but you need to "check" that file, because it could have some errors (as it is user-generated).

Comment: This would require an application restart..

Comment: This would only require some re-reading and re-creating, not a full restart.

Comment: And how-to trigger that?

Comment: All views that read those properties would need to be Recreated